# Is an array of unions valid or invalid?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, unions

Is it possible to declare an array of unions?

If yes, how is it different from a normal array of structures?

Comment: DID YOU TRY IT?

Comment: @MartinJames “just try” is not a good way to find out if things are legal in C. After all, undefined behaviour often appears to work as you expect it, until it doesn't.

Comment: If the compiler allows the union array to be declared, then it's MUCH less likely that such a structure will result in UB.

Comment: @MartinJames: Not really. There is also not "the compiler", but countless different C++ compilers with a practically infinite number of possible combinations of compiler options to choose from when you compile a piece of code.

Comment: Yes, really, and I've never seen any compiler that does not allow arrays of union structs.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, very possible (but maybe unusual).

The difference between a `struct` and a union is that a `struct` holds all its members, while a `union` only contains one member at a time.

The array members will always be big enough to hold the largest union member.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. Technically there is no difference, it's just continuous piece of memory with each element representing one union. This is exactly the same like for structure or any other type. Each elements takes the same size as size of one union or structure.